# How to assign value to variable, which name represented as other variable bash?

Tags: bash, function

I have to assign value to variable, which name represented as value of other variable. Trying this I recive tish error message:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica
Page 1
Warning in pixReadMemTiff: tiff page 1 not found
script.sh: line 39: SCORE_LIM=8000: command not found
SCORE_LIM=216353
```

Part of code:

```
function RecognizeNumber #imagename varoutput
{
    tesseract tmp/$1.tif tmp/$1 -psm 8 nobatch digits > tmp/debug_$1.txt
    "$2"=$(head -n1 tmp/$1.txt | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '-' | tr -d '.')
}
```

As u can see I'm trying to assignt some value to `$2` which are used in other function:

```
function ReadScore #geo imgname varoutput sleeptime
{
    sleep $4
    Crop $1 $2
    MakeReadible $2
    RecognizeNumber $2 $3
    echo "$3=$$3"
}
```

Here i'm trying again the same: `echo "$3=$$3"` and the most terrible part is `$$3`, i just wrote, it but did`t test it (as think it will be value of var with name`$3`).

In code I call this function as:

```
ReadScore 135x35+110+130 score SCORE_LIM 1
```

Another problem that tesseract alway show output in terminal I tried to do it with `> tmp/debug_$1.txt` but it appers anyway.

I think I do it wrong. :D Pleas help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf`; it's safer than using `eval`, which could result in unintended code from the value being executed.

```
function RecognizeNumber #imagename varoutput
{
    tesseract tmp/$1.tif tmp/$1 -psm 8 nobatch digits > tmp/debug_$1.txt
    printf -v "$2" "$(head -n1 tmp/$1.txt | tr -d ' .-')"
}
```

Also, you can get and modify the value without using external commands (and always quote your parameter expansions):

```
RecognizeNumber () {
    tesseract tmp/"$1".tif tmp/"$1" -psm8 nobatch digits > tmp/debug_"$1".txt
    read -r value < tmp/"$1".txt
    printf -v "$2" "${value//[ .-]}"
}
```

---

Indirect parameter expansion, `${!name}`, is safe.

```
function ReadScore #geo imgname varoutput sleeptime
{
    sleep "$4"
    Crop "$1" "$2"
    MakeReadible "$2"
    RecognizeNumber "$2" "$3"
    echo "$3=${!3}"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution in `eval` command and `${!variable}`construction:

```
function RecognizeNumber #imagename varoutput
{
    tesseract tmp/$1.tif tmp/$1 -psm 8 nobatch digits > tmp/debug_$1.txt
    eval $2=$(head -n1 tmp/$1.txt | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '-' | tr -d '.')
}

function ReadScore #geo imgname varoutput sleeptime
{
    sleep $4
    Crop $1 $2
    MakeReadible $2
    RecognizeNumber $2 $3
    echo "$3=${!3}"
}
```